# Lightgbm: intent of returning leaf_index

Tags: lightgbm

I am a beginner with lightgbm. Lightgbm provides a input parameter pred_leaf (false by default), which when enabled returns indices of the leafs for all the trees built during training. So for a binary classfier, with 200 trees, the predict_proba function returns a 200 * batch_size long array of indices. Although it does seem to provide some information about the model internals, I am not sure what to use these for? Can anyone please suggest, how these leaf indices maybe of help in interpreting or debugging the model?

Reference: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict_proba

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To make this specific for others reading the post, here's a small reproducible example using `pred_leaf=True`. Note that the behavior for `.predict()` and `.predict_proba()` is identical when you pass `pred_leaf=True`.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

leaf_preds = clf.predict(X, pred_leaf=True)
```

Examining the first 5 trees with `leaf_preds[:,:5]` gives output like the following

```
array([[ 4,  2,  9,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 11,  6,  9,  9],
       [ 4, 11, 13, 12, 16],
       ...,
       [ 4,  4,  6,  9,  9],
       [ 4, 11, 14, 14, 11],
       [ 6,  6,  8,  6,  7]], dtype=int32)
```

If you pass the training data back into `.predict(pred_leaf=True)`, this output could help you to understand if training started hitting tree-level stopping criteria later in the process. For example, if you used `num_leaves=50` but the maximum of a column in the `pred_leaf` output for the training data is `25`, that tells you that some iterations weren't able to find enough informative splits. You can also get at this type of information using `Booster.trees_to_dataframe()` if you'd prefer.

```py
clf.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()
```

If you pass some evaluation data (data not seen in training) into `predict(pref_leaf=True)`, it could be used to detect importance differences between the training data and the evaluation data which might otherwise be hard to see. For example, if you use `predict(X_eval, pred_leaf=True)` with evaluation data that you think is representative, you can figure out how often each leaf node is matched. If some leaf nodes match 0 or very very few of the evaluation records, that might give you confidence that a smaller model could perform just as well, which could be important if your deployment strategy is sensitive to model size.

Alternatively, that scenario might be a sign of drift in your data...if most of the evaluation data is falling into only a subset of the leaf nodes, that might be a sign that the data you're scoring on comes from a different distribution than the data the model was trained on, which might be a sign that you'd benefit from re-training on newer data.